# Using .NET Function Framework with multiple Google Cloud HTTP Functions in one project; how to set entry point for debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, google-cloud-functions

I'm using .NET Function Framework to create and deploy some C# HTTP Functions to Google Cloud. I have multiple HTTP Functions defined in a single project.

How can I set the entry point in Visual Studio so I can specify which one to debug?

Or is there a way to debug so they are all listening at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/running/function-frameworks) on Google's own documentation.

In Visual Studio you can run the following command from the PMC with the target argument:

```
dotnet run --target Namespace.MyFunctionName
```

Or edit the arguments in Debug > Debug Properties > Command Line Arguments:

```
--target Namespace.MyFunctionName
```

Then you can debug using F5 as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the following approach:

```cs
#if DEBUG
internal class DebugDispatch : IHttpFunction
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, IHttpFunction> Functions = new Dictionary<string, IHttpFunction>
    {
        ["FunctionA"] = new FunctionA(),
        ["FunctionB"] = new FunctionB(),
        ["FunctionC"] = new FunctionC(),
    };

    private static readonly Exception NotFound = new Exception("No function found to call.");

    public Task HandleAsync(HttpContext context)
        => !context.Request.Query.TryGetValue("_endpoint", out var endpoint) ? Task.FromException(NotFound)
            : !Functions.TryGetValue(endpoint, out var function) ? Task.FromException(NotFound)
            : function.HandleAsync(context);
}
#endif
```

Then you can debug with `--target Namespace.DebugDispatch`, and call your functions like so:

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/?_endpoint=FunctionA`